# Azure portal login in Microsoft Edge redirect to https://atge.okta.com

Tags: windows, azure, outlook, office365, microsoft-edge

My Microsoft edge browser is sign up with my personal hotmail account. But when I browse azure portal and trying to log in, the portal page invoke https://atge.okta.com login option associated with my previous university which I no longer had access. I am not able to login to azure portal. How can I remove this https://atge.okta.com login option associated with university  from the edge.  I am attaching the screenshot of that log in. Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvpw2.png)

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: I did. but it doesn't help

Comment: Based on what you're trying to get InPrivate mode working correctly, I think you could try troubleshooting what extensions are installed in Edge.

Comment: yeah, i choose private mode only to get instant solution to log in easily. But I add new profile on my edge browser and now it is not redirecting like before. Looks it get solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try a few different things:

1. Clear your browser cache, history, cookies, etc. Verify that the check boxes for `Browsing history`, `Download history`, `Cookies`, and `Cached images and files` are selected.
2. Open an `Incognito/Private` instance of your browser and attempt to access https://portal.azure.com and see if it lets your login with your personal account. This is a simple sanity check letting you know that your issue is, indeed derived from some kind of credential caching by the browser.
3. Reset your browser settings to defaults using the `Reset Settings` option in Edge's `Settings` view.
4. You can also try a workaround and access: [https://my.visualstudio.com/?campaign=o~msft~msdn~nav~subscriber](https://my.visualstudio.com/?campaign=o%7Emsft%7Emsdn%7Enav%7Esubscriber) and login there with your personal account. According to some users this helps clear some cached credentials.
5. Open `Credential Manager` in Windows and remove any and all references to your `Office 365` account that is causing issues.
6. If none of this works, the final option is to make sure that your device isn't being managed by your old college. In Windows, open `Settings --> Accounts --> Access Work or School` and make sure you `unlink` your device from your old school account.

EDIT: Because your issue only appears in Edge, I’m leaning towards it being an Edge/Windows Profile issue. Edge has a feature called “Automatic Profile Switching” which changes your Edge profile to “Work/School” for certain URLs. Disabling the feature doesn’t always work correctly, so I recommend simply removing your old school profile from both Windows Accounts and Edge.

Comment: I tried Option 1 and 3 and it doesn't work. Tried 2 and had no issue with login. So option 2 safe as of now. Will try 5. For option 6) don't think any issue. I downloaded chrome and try to login and it works. The issue only with Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve that issue by replacing existing one with new profile on edge browser.

```
Like in edge, open Settings --> Profile --> Add new profile.
```

Thanks for everyone.